# ¿Es correcto decir "tiempo material"?

Tags: gramática, expresiones

Se oye con frecuencia la construcción **tiempo material**, generalmente para mencionar la ausencia de él:

> [**tiempo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Zir6Ipf)
>
> *no tener tiempo material*
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. No disponer del que estrictamente se necesita para algo. *No tuve tiempo material para escribirte.*

A mí me suena normal porque lo he oído toda la vida. Ahora bien, conceptualmente me parece algo raro: ¿cómo puede ser material algo intangible?

¿No sería más correcto enfatizar la ausencia de tiempo con algo así como "No tuve tiempo *en absoluto* para..." o alguna construcción similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay una acepción de *material* que es

> **[material](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ObWToYw)**
>
> Del lat. *materiālis*.
>
> 2. adj. Opuesto a lo espiritual.

Sin entrar en discusiones acerca de qué es el tiempo, que los físicos aún están tratando de esclarecer qué es, el tiempo será intangible pero desde luego es algo real, y por tanto es opuesto a lo espiritual. Así que no es descabellado hablar de *tiempo material*.

Sobre tu opción alternativa: a mí me suena que "no tuve tiempo en absoluto" significa "no tuve nada de tiempo disponible", mientras que "no tuve tiempo material" significa "tuve algo de tiempo pero no el suficiente".

Sobre que lo has oído toda la vida: en Ngram [se puede ver](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tiempo%20material&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctiempo%20material%3B%2Cc0) que empezó a usarse en la primera mitad del siglo XIX (lo anterior son falsos positivos).

Comment: Lo que confirma que tengo menos de 150 años : )

Comment: This looks like 'un falso amigo' as in English the material time is the relevant one. 'The husband could not have killed his wife because at the material time he was in the bar watching the football.'

Comment: Pero entonces, ¿no es redundante? ¿qué añade la partícula "material"?

Comment: @fedorqui pues mira, redundante sí que parece. ¿O no? ¿Sería lo mismo decir "no tuve tiempo para escribirte"? ¿Tiene la misma connotación? Posiblemente decir "tiempo material" sea una forma de decir que no tuviste tiempo porque no te dejaron o porque estabas de verdad ocupado con otras cosas más urgentes, más que porque no tuvieras ganas de sacar tiempo. Pero ahí ya entro en especulaciones.

Comment: Entiendo. A mí me parece redundante, pero también es verdad que de tanto oírlo también me parece incluso necesario en algún caso. Es decir, enfatiza la ausencia de tiempo suficiente. Por ello inicié la pregunta, pues no sé si el uso me ha hecho perder la noción de su necesidad.